AWS S3 Folder Download API with Lambda Integration
The Problem is We need a way which let's us download a Aws s3 Folder in a zip if user passes nothing than whole contetnt of the bucket, while creating a zip of the content.
My Approach
I gets the keys of the prefix that user passes
After Getting keys i calls GetObjectCommand to get readstream of the keys
And pushes it to the archive which is also a readable stream
Here' lies the problem
I than creates that stream into a a base64 string as i am using a lamda which has set content-dispositon in the header
It works fine if the content of a folder is less in size but for large size objects the lamda gets timeOut
export async function streamToString(stream, encoding): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks: Buffer[] | any[] = [];
    stream.on("data", (chunk: string | Buffer | any) => chunks.push(chunk));
    stream.on("error", reject);
    stream.on("end", () =>
      resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString(encoding ? encoding : "utf8")),
    );
  });
}

the above is the code which converts stream of the zip into string
    const archive = archiver(compresionMode, {
      zlib: { level: 9 }, // Set compression level
    });

    // Iterate through each object key
    client.logger.info("getting object from the keys");
    for (const key of keys) {
      // Get the object from S3
      const command = new GetObjectCommand({
        Bucket: client.bucket,
        Key: key,
      });

      const response = await client.s3client.send(command);
      // Append the file to the zip archive
      archive.append(response.Body, { name: key });
    }


the above is the basic code of my method which looops to the array of keys and gets the stream of the object and adds it the zip which gets converted after this process with streamToString method

You can increase the Lambda function timeout and you can configure it with more RAM to get more CPU, so investigate those options. There are, however, fundamental limits to what you can do within the max duration of a Lambda function.

Yeah This is the only way solution i got so far but still lamda can run max upto 15 mint i guess i am struggling with this thing now thanks for the ans
